# AJAX Done Callback to prevent requests from interrupting each other

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, batch

I am trying to make sure my client-side code does not send another request before it receives a reply. To the best of my knowledge the code I will post is supposed to do this but I am still getting a -1 for `$return`.

The AJAX request repeatedly gets the echoed value of a function which is using a batch file to get the size of a file that is being uploaded via FTP. The application using this shifted storage and is now in UNC path and now the AJAX gets nothing in return.

If I run the bat file manually I can get a response, but it might take 1 second or it might take a minute, for some reason there doesn't seem to be a lot in the middle. If I use the PHP script to call it I get `$out` equal to an empty array and `$return` equal to -1. My guess is that it's taking so long to process the request the Ajax requests are interrupting each other.

**Ajax:**

I am using `ajaxTime` to try and see how long the requests are taking. They are varying from usually around 550-650 response time:

```
var ajaxTime = new Date().getTime();
getdSize(f, ajaxTime);

function getSize(f, ajaxTime){
        $.ajax({
            url: "php file handling the ajax request",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                file : encodeURIComponent(f),
                }
            })
        .done(function(data){
            var totalTime = new Date().getTime()-ajaxTime;
            console.log("Ajax Time: " + totalTime);
            console.log("Data: " + data);
        })
        .fail(function(data){
            if ( data.responseCode ){
              console.log( data.responseCode );
            }
            console.log("Ajax failure");
        });
    }
```

**PHP:**

```
    $file = $_POST['file'];
    echo bat_getSize($file);
[this calls bat_getSize function]

function bat_getSize($file){
    exec("getSize \"$file\"",$out, $ret);
    return $out[0];
}
```

Which calls this batch code:

```
@echo off
echo %~z1
```

Answer (score 2):

To be sure that nothing happens before the AJAX request is achieved, you can simply add the `async: false` property to your `$.ajax({...})`.

---

As pointed by @Tom Stickel, doing so fires a warning about future deprecation of `async: false`.

I agree, and this is already known from times but, as stated in paragraph 4.5.1 of [the page he cited](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/):

> This is a long process that takes many years

It's why I suggest this solution (and also am using it somewhat frequently), but:

1. *only in the case of this kind of situation*, where the "detrimental effects to the end user's experience" is clearly not involved (at the opposite, here, it's precisely what is expected)
2. *only for now*, considering it's worth applying a so simple solution as long as it works, and change it only when deprecation will effectively happen (note that the involved piece of code might be obsolete first!)

Comment: Well you most likely will get this message in Chrome:    Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Comment: @TomStickel Indeed it's true and I didn't ignored it, but also didn't make the effort to clearly explain why I nevertheless proposed it. Sure it was a lack in my answer: it's now filled, thanks to you.